# Different links for different groups SPS 3.0

Tags: quick-launch

I got a perfect answer to a simlar question in MOSS2007, but I need a solution for my Sharepoint Services 3.0 enviroment.

I've got several views for a specific list. Depending on their usergroup, users should see different links to different views. Group1 for example should see link 1,2 and 3...while group2 should see link 4 and 5.

How can I realize this with the lag of audiences in Sharepoint Services? Can I change the behaviour of the quicklaunch? Or does anybody have another good solution for my problem?

Thanks in advance

Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve what you ask is to use jQuery to hide the links in the Quick Launch.  You would use the SPServices project to retrieve the user's group, then hide or show your links accordingly.  Marc Anderson has much of the code already detailed here: http://sympmarc.com/2010/01/29/determining-if-a-user-is-in-a-permission-group-with-sharepoints-web-services/

I wanted to advise you, though, that users can still access all the views if they know the URL to them.  In other words, while using different views from the same list targeted toward different users may be a good personalization feature, it is not a good security feature. Using separate lists would be more secure.

Comment: Thanks Rob! jquery was a very good advice. Although I'm not sooo familar with Javascript, it works great. I'm trying to get the links I want to hide, but quicklaunch doesn't tag them well in my opinion.
Thanks a lot!